# Debug main page javascript with chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

I have no problem using the chrome dev tool to debug (and edit in real time) my scripts that are not in my index page but i would like to to if it possible to do the same for script that are directly in a page

ex:

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    echo 'test';
  //-->
  </script>
 </body>
```

No way i can edit this in the source tab.

But if i load that in a external file i will be able to edit it.

did firebug or any other tools can do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to select the `script` element in the Elements tab, before right-clicking it and seletcting "Edit as HTML" or by selecting the contents of the script element, right-clicking and choosing "Edit as Text" or "Edit as HTML"?

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt work for javascript.